# Using mongo-java-driver to manipulate arrays

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I'm using `mongo-java-driver-2.11.2`. I got stuck with array manipulation. I succeed in creating an array but failed with an exception of `bad key: "$PUSH"` while trying to insert an element into the array. Here is my code:

```
DBCursor cursor = iiCollection.find(new BasicDBObject(TOKEN, token.getToken()));
if(cursor.hasNext()){
    DBObject o = cursor.next();
    int freq   = (Integer) o.get(FREQ);
    iiCollection.update(o, new BasicDBObject(FREQ, freq + 1)
                    .append("$push", new BasicDBObject(DOCS, docId)));
}
else{
    iiCollection.insert(new BasicDBObject(TOKEN, token.getToken())
                    .append(FREQ, 1)
                    .append(DOCS, new String[]{docId}));
}
```

The 'else' branch is ok, but the first branch won't work, please help me figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick:

```
iiCollection.update(o, new BasicDBObject("$set",new BasicDBObject("freq", freq+1)).append("$push", new BasicDBObject("docs", 1)));
```

The reason for this is that when you execute the code like below,

```
new BasicDBObject("freq", freq+1).append("$push", new BasicDBObject("docs", 1))
```

it converts to

```
{ "freq" : 3 , "$push" : { "docs" : 1}}
```

which is incorrect.